# Unpurged 'related question' comment no longer linked in the sidebar?

Tags: bug, comments

After the comments were purged [on this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37421/what-are-some-of-the-benefits-of-having-a-mac-vs-a-windows-pc-in-a-design-enviro) and then my related question comment was unpurged, it is no longer a linked question on the right hand side.

Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: Huh. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Nope! I'm assuming it's working its way through the bug queue. I'll see if I can get word on its status, though.

Comment: Hm. As I dig more it turns out it might be by design. Workarounds are re-commenting (and deleting the previous comment) or edit the link into the question or an answer. See if that brings it back to the sidebar.